# Is there any demand for MathJax on Law.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While answering a few questions, I've wished we had MathJax enabled on the site.  It's a JavaScript library that displays mathematical notation in web browsers, using a couple markup languages including LaTeX.

The wishing hasn't been motivated by a desire to write hideous math equations (which I don't think the audience would care for) so much as some basic stuff that might complement the text.

What we've got works quite well, but given that the feature is installed on a number of other SE sites, I'm wondering if it'd be as easy as flipping a switch.

Comment: Yep, it's a switch. You may want to turn this into a feature request :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 thanks; edited accordingly

Comment: Do you have an example of an answer you've written that would be improved by MathJax? Personally, I've never felt that I would need/want it, but it's possible that that stems from an ignorance as to what I might be able to do with it, rather than a genuine lack of need.

Comment: @jimsug I'm imagining some simple cost-benefit stuff, but a second advantage is that MathJax interprets LaTeX.  As an example, the section symbol '§' is just `$\S$`, which is nice for those of us without a keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 4):

Given the way it is presently implemented on Stack Exchange, [there is overhead to supporting MathJAX on a site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/2662901).

For context, [here is a list of the SE sites that have chosen to pay that performance price](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/241697).

For the special characters that would be natural for this site I would encourage people to just learn the HTML codes – e.g., `&sect;` = §

Comment: Ugh.  That's a heavy penalty; I retract my interest